# Scrolling a div with touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

How can I scroll a div with touch events? I have a DIV with overflow set to hidden. I know I can scroll a DIV with javascript, here is an example for using the mousewheel:

```
function mousewheelScroll(event, delta) {
    var $t = $(this);
    var change = delta * 8;
    var top = $t.scrollTop();
    top = top - change;
    if (top < 0)
        top = 0;
    if (top > ($t.attr("scrollHeight") - $t.innerHeight()))
        top = ($t.attr("scrollHeight") - $t.innerHeight());
    $t.scrollTop(top);
}
```

But i haven't found an example that will work with touch events for iOS devices.

Comment: Are there touch events specifically for mobile devices? That'd be news to me, but I don't really target mobile applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this plugin, it seems like it's just what you're looking for

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/touch-scroll

Comment: Did you get touchScroll to work? We can't get the content to stay at the newly scrolled position. The content always snaps back to its original position after someone flicks up or down.